# Is it possible to refresh UIView on UITableViewCell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I placed UIView over UITableViewCell which is for drawing custom view like simple chart view.
Then I tried to refresh UIView once new data is coming. But it does not work. I would want to know the way I did is right or not. Or there is another way to refresh UIView.

```
Here is code fragment.





   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];   
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//


        graphView = [[ChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 5, 18, 36)];                                 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:graphView];
        [graphView release];


         nameLabel                      = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 105.0, 45.0)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
        [StockNameLabel release];

}

....

..
return cell;
}



- (void)realTimeData:(NSMutableDictionary *)data {  <--- its a call back method

             NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];  
            UITableViewCell  *cell = [m_InterestTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
            ChartView *chartView =  (ChartView*)[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
            [chartView initWithPrices:sPrice withcPrice:cPrice withlPrice:lPrice withhPrice:hPrice];

}

ChartView

- (void) refreshScreen{    
      [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //get graphic context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextClearRect(context, rect);


    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,2.0f);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1,y1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,x2, y2);
    [RGB(r,g, b) set];
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextAddRect(context,fillArea);
    [RGB(r, g, b) set];
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}
```

Comment: whoa...why are you calling init on your ChartView in the realTimeData: callback?

Comment: the init is nothing but to feed data. Take a look code

-(void)initWithPrices:(CGFloat)lstPrice withsPrice:(CGFloat)sPrice withcPrice:(CGFloat)cPrice withlPrice:(CGFloat)lPrice withhPrice:(CGFloat)hPrice  {
    
    _lstPrice = lstPrice;
    _sPrice   = sPrice;
    _cPrice   = cPrice;
    _hPrice   = hPrice;
    _lPrice   = lPrice;
    
    [self refreshScreen];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is the one you have implemented yourself. It creates a new table cell to be used at the specified index path. It doesn't and should return an existing one (except for the recycling of no longer used cells).

So you basically have two options:

1. Keep a reference to the table cell that will be updated at a later time. Then you can directly update it once new data arrives. It's a bit tricky because you'll need to detect whether the table cell has been moved out of view and been recycled to be used for a different table row.
2. Ask the table view to reload the affect cell:

   ```
   NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cellIndexPath , nil] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   [tableView endUpdates];
   ```

   The table view will then call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you can create a new cell with the latest data.

Comment: Then, can I try like this?

NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
 [tableView beginUpdates];
 [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cellIndexPath , nil] withRowAnimation:   UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];         
UITableViewCell  *cell = [myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
            ChartView *chartView =  (ChartView*)[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
            [chartView initWithPrices:sPrice withcPrice:cPrice withlPrice:lPrice withhPrice:hPrice];

Comment: You better put the code at the end of your question. It will be much easier to read. And some non-code (comment, further question, feedback) couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Sorry for messy.  My question is that.
1. After reloading a certain cell, I can refresh graphView with the cell reference?. Am I correct?.

Comment: No, you don't refresh the graphView. Instead, your code will be called and can deliver a new cell. This cell will need to be created with latest data.

Comment: Based on your comment, I should follow option #1 because option #2 always creates a new cell. Can you point me simple example?. Its hard to understand the first one.

Comment: I don't understand why you rule out option 1. Can you explain it? And it seems to me that the data you want to display in the the table view isn't stored anywhere separate from the table cells. If this is the case, then you'll have a problem because if the users moves/scrolls a table cell out of the screen and into it again, then you'll loose the data since the table cell is discarded and recreated.

Comment: I tested the second one. it works because  each cell has  key value, so once the key matches then, refresh the cell.  Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you get access to the ChartView instance, then call `refreshScreen`, it should refresh the view. From the code provided, I see no evidence of this happening. In fact, it looks like you're trying to initialize an already initialized ChartView, which is always bad news.